storing and retrieving a string in tcomponent.tag using freepascal
I want to store this string expression:
oField.displayname+'='+varTostr(fieldbyname(ofield.fieldame).value)
where ofield is TField of dataset in TComponent.Tag. How can I do this?
I am using FreePascal.

Please add what you have tried and what is the expected output.

The Tag field of a TComponent is of type PtrInt, which is large enough to store a pointer, including the memory address of a string. You can use the Tag to store the address of a dynamically allocated string.
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyString: PChar;
begin
  MyString := StrAlloc(100);
  StrPCopy(MyString, 'Hello, Free Pascal!');
  Label1.Tag := PtrInt(MyString);
  Edit1.Text := PChar(Label1.Tag);
  StrDispose(PChar(Label1.Tag));
end;

Ensure that the memory is always properly deallocated to avoid leaks or dangling pointers
